# What dependencies does Kdenlive 16.12 or above need to have in advance?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, make, kdenlive

My current version of Kdenlive is 15.12.3, I installed it with apt-get right from the repository. 
However, I need version 16.12 or above in order to use the rotoscoping feature.

To this point, I have only installed software from the standard repository with apt-get, but there is only one version. So I want to install it manually from source, I am unsure how to make it, I read I need to know how the program make works, how to use the program tar to unzip files, chmod to make it excutable  and I have to get the dependencies myself.

So, to advance, I would like to make at least the first step and get the necessary dependencies, but I do not know how to look them up for this specific version of this program.

Is there a kind of telephone book where to each version of a programm the necessary dependencies are listed or how do you usually retrieve this info?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did you try a ppa ? See https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable That ppa has 16.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to ask probably not the best of ideas to compile.

Use the ppa - version 16.12 - https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To compile see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

For additional information on ppa see [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: when I do  the last step: apt-get upgrade  , does my kdenlive version becomes the newer version without having to install it separately?

Comment: Yes upgrade installs the latest version and updates your system including any dependencies.

Comment: strangely, when I typed   apt-cache policy kdenlive   the old version was still marked as installed, but the newer version has become an installation candidate...

Comment: try apt-cache policy kdenlive-stable